# is there an equivalent to quokkajs for emacs

Tags: javascript, emacs

(I don't know a better place to ask an army of developers)

So...I just came across this plugin (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_sEWa5hA0Q&t=3s) that allows JavasSript code to be ran inline in VSCode and Jetbrains. BUT... I want to know if some opensource tool exist that does  --the exact-- thing for emacs?

the ability to run JS code inside the editor inline is the killer-app in my opinion. Is it possible for emacs?

Right when I'm trying to move exclusively to emacs, this shows up.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like quokkajs is something like [org-babel](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/) for Emacs `org-mode`, except that org-babel supports about 80 languages, and quokkajs supports 1 language.